# How to open some thread handle alltime request?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot

Here are my questions, please give me some suggestions, thanks a lot.

1. We are want to build a spring boot application and will start some threads to request to our supplier for some import infos.
2. Our supplier do not support callback way, we must request all times.
3. Now we do is when application start ,we start 40 thread(use TaskExecutor) for every supplier(we have about 7 suppliers), in
   every thread we request to supplier to find if have some sending
   status back. when back ,we save on mongodb. if not ,continue.
4. We want to know if there are some other solutions?

Comment: You have explained your design. Can you specify what do you have to do or what is the problem or is there any requirement you can't fulfilling by this design?

Comment: This design will word fine, but some time the thread will die , in the log there is no error logs display.  so i want to find a better way to solve..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring TaskScheduler](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler)

It can help you following:

1. Thread can be executed by interval, cron, periodical or in fixed rate.
2. No need to monitor thread for dead. It will always execute as scheduled.

Comment: yes, I think of it . but ,where is a question , we have lots of data to recycle, so we start 40 Threads for every supplier . if we use Scheduler , we can scheduler lots of taskScheduler  in seconds?

Comment: You don't have to use lot of TaskScheduler. I think you can use 7 TaskScheduler and every TaskScheduler having maximum pool of 40. So that, you can use one TaskScheduler for one supplier.

Comment: OK , I wll try . Thanks a lot.